# Вопрос в вопросе.

Tags: лингвистика

Часто по телевидению  наблюдал подобное сочетание вроде "спросить вопрос". Корректно ли данное сочетание - или все таки "задать вопрос"?
И еще, как правильно будет - "у меня к тебе сюрприз" или "у меня для тебя сюрприз"?

Answer (score 4):

Спросить вопрос - это масло масляное, иначе говоря, тавтология. Вопрос можно задать, а спросить можно человека, спросить можно чьего-то мнения, но никак не вопрос)))

Comment: Правильно будет "У меня для тебя сюрприз".

Comment: А "у меня к тебе" может быть предложение.